# Array starting at Zero

Tags: php, arrays

Why doesnt this work? I need it to start out at 1 instead of 0. And if I change $i to = 1 then it doesnt grab the first row.
http://www.mcregister.com/beta/test.php

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['question'])) {  
   for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['question']);$i++) {  
      $question=$_POST['question'][$i]."<br />"; echo "<b>Question $i:</b> $question";  
   }    
}  
?>
```

EDIT: Instead of starting out at 1.. I just need it to echo starting with "Question 1:" instead of "Question 0:".

Comment: Why the heck do you need to start out at one? Especially if you want the first row??

Comment: don't try to ix something that is not broken.

Comment: I should rephrase.. the count works fine.. but then I do the last echo "Question $i" that says Question 0... needs to say question 1.

Comment: Don't change the keys of the array for something this trivial. Either, `$i + 1` or, alternatively initialize another variable to keep count of the questions ?

Comment: Is there an example of this, russel? I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seem like you would like to get output

```
<b>Question 1:</b> Blah Blah
```

But. The array key is start from 0 by default

There have 2 way to get it. If you really want an array start with key number 1 . you can do by following code.

```
$new_array = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['question']);$i++) {  
      $new_array[$i+1] = $_POST['question'][$i];  
}
```

but if you want to have just 1. you can do like

```
if(isset($_POST['question'])) {  
   for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['question']);$i++) {  
      $question=$_POST['question'][$i]."<br />"; echo "<b>Question ".$i+1.":</b> $question";  
   }    
}
```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Hmm after adding this I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/organik/public_html/beta/test.php on line 238`

Comment: Line 238: `$question=$_POST['question'][$i]."<br />"; echo "<b>Question ".$i+1.":</b> $question";`

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['question'])) { foreach (($_POST['question']) as $key=>$value) { $key +=1; echo "<b>Question ".$key.":</b> $value"; } }`

Comment: Or try `$question_no = $i + 1; $question=$_POST['question'][$i]."<br />"; echo "<b>Question $question_no :</b> $question";` hope it's work

Answer (score 3):

All array keys, by default, begin at index `0` (unless explicitly stated), therefore starting at `1` will not include the first result.

Answer (score 1):

If you need posted data started with 1 (which is pointless actually) you have to change your html from

```
<input type="text" name="question[]" class="text">
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="question[1]" class="text">
```

etc

Comment: @Brandon: doesn't work is not an explanation of a problem. On such question the only answer I can give is: "so fix it somehow"

Comment: It just made it not echo anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is output each question (without any validation!) you don't need the question variable at all.  Just do:

```
echo 'Question #' . ($i + 1) . ': ' . $_POST['question'][$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

For all the answers here.. and i'm sure they know it.. for logical and simple reason, start your array at zero. Because.. like `Russel Dias` says: all array start at 0. If you don't want to make it complicated, start it at 0.

A high recommandation of all programmers :D
Good Luck!

Comment: Oh, just add +1 at your `$i`
Like : `echo "<b>Question".$i+1.":</b>"`