# Re-index numeric array keys

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I have an array that is built using the `explode()` function, but seeing how i'm using it with random/dynamic data, i see that the indexes keep changing:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Title: Warmly little before cousin sussex entire set Blessing it ladyship.
    [3] => Snippet: Testing
    [4] => Category: Member
    [5] => Tags: little, before, entire
)
```

I need the array to be ordered starting at 0 always. I am testing with different data and sometimes it starts at 0, and with other tests it begins at different numbers.
I researched and came across [Array starting at zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113325/array-starting-at-zero) but it seems that only applied to that users specific case. The code i'm using to build the array can be seen here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10484967/1183323

How can i do this?

Comment: How did you build this array? Explode by default would start at 0.

Comment: Did you [read the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
$your_new_array = array_values($your_old_array);
```

Comment: This did it, but should there be anything else i should be concerned about implementing this function.

Comment: No. According to the manual, "array_values() returns all the values from the input array and indexes numerically the array."

Comment: Note that the manual does not guarantee that order of values will be preserved.

Answer (score 12):

Use [array_merge()](http://php.net/array_merge) to renumber the array:

```
$your_old_array = array( 2 => 'whatever', 19 => 'huh', 22 => 'yep' );
$your_new_array = array_merge($your_old_array);
print_r($your_new_array);
```

Prints this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => whatever 
  [1] => huh 
  [2] => yep )
```

Comment: This also works, the result i achieved is similar to that of `array_values`, thanks!

Comment: This is similar to array_values but better if you have also string keys in the array along with numeric keys.  array_merge()  keeps the string keys as it is and rearrange only numeric keys.

Comment: I would argue that `array_merge` is the better answer. If there are any non-numerical array indices in the array, `array_values` will remove them and re-number them.Only `array_merge` will preserve non-numerical indices whilst re-indexing only numerical indices.