# Rearrange array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem like,array with 0 10 indexes and i removed 0th index now it's like 1 to 10
when i display this array there is an empty column in 0th position.I want to rearrange this array to 0 to 9.
The purpose is the array construct my grid and 0th position is for edit ,if a user doesn't have the permission then i unset the 0th element.
How do i rearrange my array to 0 to 9

Sample array structure is like

```
[fields] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [header] => Array
                    (
                        [fieldName] => OFFERID
                        [displayName] => History
                        [width] => 70
                    )

                [visibility] => Array
                    (
                        [showOnStart] => 1
                        [editable] => 
                    )

                [cell] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => raw
                        [params] => Array
                            (
                                [text] => <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="{{OFFERID}}" class="btnHistory">History</a>
                            )

                    )

                [sort] => Array
                    (
                        [sortable] => 1
                    )

                [validator] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 
                        [params] => 
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [header] => Array
                    (
                        [fieldName] => OFFERID
                        [displayName] => Offer Id
                        [group] => 0
                    )
```

thanks
Alex

Comment: How are you removing the value from the array?

Comment: How are you iterating through the array and displaying it?

Comment: Use [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift)  to remove the first value, the numbers will be re-indexed as you use numeric keys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Re-index numeric array keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524156/re-index-numeric-array-keys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`array_splice`](http://www.php.net/array_splice) to remove a portion of the array.

`array array_splice ( array &$input , int $offset [, int $length = 0 [, mixed $replacement ]] )`

For example:

```
$array = array(0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c");
array_splice($array, 0, 1);
var_dump($array);
```

Will output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(1) "b"
  [1]=> string(1) "c"
}
```

Notice it will re-index your array, as you requested.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways to do this, here are the two shortest ones ([`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)/[`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)):

```
$array = array_values($array);
// or
$array = array_merge($array);
```

But you might think about using [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)/[`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)/[`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to remove the item from the the array instead of (presumably) `unset()`ing it - these will automatically shift all the keys into a contiguous 0-indexed order.

Comment: Sometimes the edit may come another position at present it's 0th position so only unset is applicable for me.

Comment: @user1390436 Actually [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) will let you remove elements from the array at the nth position, and reorder the keys in one operation - I have edited my answer.

Comment: which is exactly what I suggested initially :)

Comment: @DvirAzulay Indeed it is, and you have my +1 :-)