# array_unique and then renumbering keys

Tags: php, array-unique

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Re-index numeric array keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524156/re-index-numeric-array-keys)

I have an array as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15/11/2012 - 18/11/2012
    [1] => 15/11/2012 - 18/11/2012
    [2] => 15/11/2012 - 18/11/2012
    [3] => 15/11/2012 - 18/11/2012
    [4] => 19/12/2012 - 24/12/2012
    [5] => 24/12/2012 - 01/01/2013
    [6] => 24/12/2012 - 01/01/2013
    [7] => 16/01/2013 - 01/02/2013
)
```

I am using array_unique to remove the duplicates which is giving me

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 15/11/2012 - 18/11/2012
    [4] => 19/12/2012 - 24/12/2012
    [5] => 24/12/2012 - 01/01/2013
    [7] => 16/01/2013 - 01/02/2013
)
```

How can I change the keys so that they are consecutive - as below

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 15/11/2012 - 18/11/2012
    [1] => 19/12/2012 - 24/12/2012
    [2] => 24/12/2012 - 01/01/2013
    [3] => 16/01/2013 - 01/02/2013
)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `$array = array_values($your_output_array)`  [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) will renumber the keys.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Easiest way would be to put them into a new array either via a loop, or better yet `array_values` function.

`$new_array = array_values($original_array)`

[More information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: For me this solution didn't work. I forced to use this: `array_values(array_unique($array))` and it worked correctly