# Removing non-unique PHP array values from unassociated array

Tags: php, arrays

The following code:

```
$ids=['one','two','three','two','four'];
echo('<pre>'.print_r($ids,1).'</pre>');
$ids = array_unique($ids);
echo('<pre>'.print_r($ids,1).'</pre>');
```

produces the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => two
    [4] => four
)

Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [4] => four
)
```

How do I preserve consecutive array indexes and produce the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => four
)
```

Comment: @PrototypeChain  Thank you.  Sorry, I searched and didn't find it.

Comment: it's a strange question as for `6,852` reputation

Comment: PrototypeChain first commented that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596128/array-unique-and-then-renumbering-keys was a possible duplicate, but then deleted the comment.  I don't agree that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591094/how-do-you-reindex-an-array-in-php directly answered my question, but PrototypeChain's did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more line 
`array_values($ids)`

Comment: Dang, I was so close!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_values`.

Check out the manual: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php