# PHP - Search if values are in array

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I have these arrays:

```
$array = array();
array_push($array, array("id" => 1, "param" => "abc"));
array_push($array, array("id" => 2, "param" => "def"));
array_push($array, array("id" => 3, "param" => "ghi"));

[{"id":1,"param":"abc"},{"id":2,"param":"def"},{"id":3,"param":"ghi"}]


$search = array(1, 2);
```

I need to remove the object, making a search, if the **$array** contains **$search** value.

The final array should go like this:

```
[{"id":3,"nom":"ghi"}]
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array_filter($array, function($obj) use($search) {
  return !in_array($obj['id'], $search);
});
```

Depending on how you are using the new array, you may have to [re-index it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10524156/142162).